# What math background do I need to read ESL effectively?

Tags: machine-learning, references, statistical-learning

What is an appropriate amount of mathematical background for reading *The Elements of Statistical Learning*? Of course, more is always better, but what are the key things you'd recommend a reader know before diving in, in order to get a worthwhile experience out of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of Mathematics one does not need a heavy background for a first comprehensive read of ESL. What a first year CS/Engineering undergraduate would know is adequate. For example, in terms of Linear Algebra the levels of G. Strang's [Introduction to Linear Algebra](http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/) and in terms of Multivariate Calculus J. Stewart's [Calculus](http://stewartcalculus.com/media/16_home.php) will get you through most of ESL without any issues. Refreshing your basic conditional probabilities will not go to waste either.

Some topics like the ones based on [reproducing Hilbert kernel spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space), [wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet) and [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling) will not be fully accessible and one would probably need to read about them separately in order to fully grasp them. Nevertheless the book tries to explain them in a relative straightforward manner so the reader can obtain enough working knowledge to get the gist of the text.

Check the thread [Can you recommend a book to read before Elements of Statistical Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18973/can-you-recommend-a-book-to-read-before-elements-of-statistical-learning) too. It is not really concerned with Mathematical preliminaries but rather with "conceptual ones" mostly. As a somewhat smoother and more mathematically self-contained alternative to ESL you might want to consider K. Murphy's [Machine Learning: a Probabilistic Perspective](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/).